# Cross-platform library for separating and converting PDFs to images?

Tags: pdf, image-processing, cross-platform, rasterizing

I'm currently planning an application which involves manipulating PDFs. My goal is to have a program that i can pass in a PDF as an input which then saves separated grayscale images of the colour channels that the PDF consists of as an output. This is basically a simple [RIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raster_image_processor).

I'm currently using a solution using [GhostScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghostscript) but i want to rewrite the application to optimise speed and usability. (GhostScript doesn't separate PDFs for example.)

Do you know of any other open source libraries that i may find useful to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you ever try to run (I'm assuming Windows here):

```
 mkdir separated

 gswin32c.exe ^
    -o separated/page_%04d.tif ^
    -sDEVICE=tiffsep ^
    d:/path/to/input.pdf
```

(you can also try `-sDEVICE=tiffsep1`) and then looked at the files you've gotten in the `separated` sub directory?!? And this is not a case of *Ghostscript separated PDFs* in your mind?

The device ***tiffsep*** creates multiple output files:

1. One single 32bit composite CMYK file (tiff32nc format) per PDF page.
2. Multiple tiffgray files (each compressed with LZW) per PDF page, one for each separation.

The device ***tiffsep1*** behaves similarly, but...

1. ...doesn't create the composite output file...
2. ...and it creates tiffg4 output files for the separations.

Comment: @Gary Willoughby: You can read up more details about Ghostscript's `tiffsep{,1}` devices in *Devices.htm* on http://svn.ghostscript.com/ghostscript/trunk/gs/doc/